# How to grep partial string? R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a file called `data` with roughly 2000 columns named as follows:

```
Open-YV2004
High-YV2004
Low-YV2004
Settle-YV2004
Change-YV2004
Wave-YV2004 
Volume-YV2004
Prev. Day Open Interest-YV2004
EFP Volume-YV2004
EFS Volume-YV2004
Block Volume-YV2004
```

the others continue to have the same names but a different prefix (`YV2004` above)

Currently I am using:

```
Volume <- new[,grep("Volume", colnames(data))]
```

this greps all columns containing `"Volume"` in their name:

```
Volume-YV2004
EFP Volume-YV2004
EFS Volume-YV2004
Block Volume-YV2004
```

I would like to take just the ones containing `"Volume"` only

Solution:

`Volume-YV2004`

Comment: `new[,grep("^Volume", colnames(data))]` maybe?

Comment: only... in the beginning? Then `^Volume` is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `^` in your regular expression to indicate that the wanted string must start with the text that follows:

```
Volume <- new[,grep("^Volume", colnames(data))]
```